# Keyboard shortcuts don't work sometimes

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

The keyboard shortcuts doesn't work SOMETIMES when I boot up the PC.
It's completelly random, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. It's all configured in the Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut menu.
For example: I use the "Print Screen" and "Open Terminal" so much, and if they don't work I have to go to the settings and set the SAME key combination again so they can work.
Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Same here.. have to rebind them. Reboot doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, did you solve it ? 
Read somewhere restarting Gala will help. Tried it but obviously won't know if it's working till shortcuts don't work again.

Comment: Figured it out. Still an issue for you ?